# Uploading Multiple Photos with MVC and creating structure on fly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload, photos

I have 2 models in my ASP.Net MVC application: Listing, Photos.

When I run a create method of my listing controller. I want to know what will be my unique listing ID, so I could create new folder for picture uploads based on that. Basically I want to be able to create structure like this for each picture: ".\Application_Data\Pictures\UserName\ListingID\picture".

The problem I am having is: I don't know what will be the listing ID, so I can't generate a listing folder name. I also can't populate picture table when I do upload because I need to have a reference to my listing.

My Models:

```
public class Listing
{
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    public string LocationAndName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to know which is the last created ID when the action is progressed? So storing your ID in your session would be the best was:
(when creating the new Listing instance in the controller)
Session["ListingId"] = myListing.ListingId;

Comment: Ok, and then what is the best way of uploading pictures while the user is populating data for a  new listing? Would it be a partial view with the picture upload function that will use the Session["ListingId"]. See, I am just trying to find the best way of uploading multiple pictures while I am in the Createview for the Listing. Something like ebay, when you create listing it allows you to add pictures to the listing before you hit the create listing submit button.

Comment: When your Listing is not yet created and therefore no id is known, you should save the uploaded files to a temporary folder until the listing has been created. Then it is created you can move the uploaded files to the Listing-folder. Just save the file paths also to the Session-object e.g. as List<strint>